# Auto loading packages to python project in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am completely new to pycharm so this might be obvious. But currently every-time I load a project in pycharm I need to re-install the packages. Is there a way to automatically load them, or keep them on the project?

Answer (score 0):

where you are installing the packages, to the python system interpreter or to the virtual environment ? If you are creating virtual env for all the projects you need to install packages everytime but if you use system python interpreter one time installation will be enough no need to install the same package again.

Answer (score 0):

The default option of PyCharm is to generate a fresh virtual environment.
Which is safe, but you need to re-install packages.

See below how to select an existing environment instead.

So you could set up one environment, install what you usually need and always use that. This is fast, but comes with a big downside: Later updates to this or other installations may break programs you wrote earlier.

As you can see, there's a checkbox that says: Make this environment available to all projects which will help you doing this.

[image: see here]